# QGIS: static Atlas, it do not follow the point-layer

Tags: qgis, windows, atlas

I do not use Atlas for years.
Now I set Atlas to follow a point layer but when I export in separate files it gives me this error:

impossible write on C:...path\name_item.pdf because the file could be used by another application or path not valid (I try with different file names and different folders)

When I try to export it as a single file it works

I start with a new project but te problem was not solved

Comment: You have the output file open in another program, close that program

Comment: I have only QGIS opened :-(

Comment: Try to export to a different folder.

Comment: What do you use as filenames? If its an attribute change that for testing to just a number. If its then working, its an invalid character in your attribute table (like linebreak, backslash, etc).

Comment: When you select map item and go to property then `controled by atlas` is checked and zoom level is set ?